# Dependant fields in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model which must be able to save information about when/what actions must be executed by a task (the task-related stuff are out of the scope of this question, so I won't get into details about that).

The actions are divided into **at least** 3 sections.

The first section is "**when**" (`before` or `after` the task has been executed), so that should show up in the django admin like a dropdown (this one is easy).

The second section is **what** action should be executed (`perform a click`, `transform a text`, `get regex match`, etc...), which should also show up as a dropdown in django's admin (this one is easy too).

Here comes the difficult part. Depending on the selection of the second section, I must show another input field(s) of some sort. For example, if I select `perform a click` in the second section, the third section would show a text field in which I should type the CSS selector for the element I want the task to click. But if I select `transform a text` in the second section, then the third section should show me a dropdown with several options such as `uppercase`, `lowercase`, `append`, etc...

If I select `uppercase`, nothing else should be shown, but if I select `append`, then another field should be shown, so I can type the text that I want to be appended.

Is there some generic way Django can handle this? Or are there any packages that I should use? Or this is DIY territory? If the later, how can I do it?